# Problem with for-loop and multiple CSV files

Tags: python

It looks like the first for loop only considers the first line in the first csv file and does not continue comparing. I have tried to rewrite it a bunch of ways but now im totally lost so im turning to you guys.

Can anyone tell me if there is anything wrong writing the code as i did here:

```
with open("./products.csv", mode="r") as products_list1:
    with open("./products2.csv", mode="r") as products_list2:
        with open("./results.csv", mode="a") as results:
            for i in products_list1:
                for j in products_list2:
                    jaccard = get_jaccard_sim(i, j)
                    if jaccard >= 0:
                        results.writelines(i+","+j+"\n"+","+str(jaccard))
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Files aren't lists and must be re-opened _each time_ before iterating over them.

Comment: `for i in products_list1:` should read `for i in products_list1.readlines():` to get an actual list to loop over

Comment: Thanks for the input. It works with .readlines()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
with open("./products.csv", mode="r") as products_list1:
    lines1 = products_list1.readlines()
with open("./products2.csv", mode="r") as products_list2:
    lines2 = products_list2.readlines()
with open("./results.csv", mode="a") as results:
    for i in lines1:
        for j in lines2:
            jaccard = get_jaccard_sim(i, j)
            if jaccard >= 0:
                results.writelines(i + "," + j + "\n" + "," + str(jaccard))
```

Comment: similar to what @Satya had mentioned here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/54944794/2987755

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this before opening any `for` loops:

```
pdt_list1 = products_list1.readlines()
pdt_list2 = products_list2.readlines()
```

and perform your operations on `pdt_list1` and `pdt_list2`.

This will fix the issue! Good Luck!